# Filter cell data using Query/Importdata

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter, importdata

I am attempting to grab data from a cell, by using additional data in the cell above it to make sure its correct.
Here is the data, each line is put into a cell by the formula.

```
<total_count>6</total_count>
<games>
<message>
<appid>376210</appid>
<name>The Isle</name>
<playtime_2weeks>4300</playtime_2weeks>
<playtime_forever>23973</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>4000</appid>
<name>Garry&apos;s Mod</name> --------using this
<playtime_2weeks>289</playtime_2weeks> ------to get this!
<playtime_forever>277810</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>578080</appid>
<name>PLAYERUNKNOWN&apos;S BATTLEGROUNDS</name>
<playtime_2weeks>59</playtime_2weeks>
<playtime_forever>8585</playtime_forever>
<img_icon_url>93d896e7d7a42ae35c1d77239430e1d90bc82cae</img_icon_url>
<img_logo_url>2d2732a33511b58c69aff6b098a22687a3bb8533</img_logo_url>
</message>
<message>
```

The formula I am currently using is

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA(A1)," select Col1,Col2 where Col2 = '2weeks' and Col2 matches 'Garry'")
```

It outputs `<name>Garry&apos;s Mod</name>` and I can't select only '2weeks' since that is repeated several times, and for different games.

Additionally, the layout may change at anytime. The Isle is current at the top, but it may change to be at the middle, or bottom of the list at any time. I know if I spent more time on this, I could just use separate formulas to achieve my goal, however I'm attempting to learn how to used combined formulas. Less clutter, more options, and easier to look at.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the htnl code in one cell or across multiple cells in column?

Comment: It is across multiple cells in one column

Comment: Each line on the OP is a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({{A1:A25; ""}, {""; A1:A25}}, 
 "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), 
 ">(.*)<")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you again, it is much appreciated.
As I stated earlier, I'm learning to combine formulas, so I attempted to combine this with our earlier discussion, using IMPORTDATA, however all I got back was `query completed with an empty output`. Is it just not possible to combine these formulas? Do I need to import the data first, as shown in your post, and then filter the data?

Comment: paste me the formula pls

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(F5), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), 
 ">(.*)<")`
I have the link that grabs all the info from above, on F5

Comment: I meant that IMPORT fx which is F5

Comment: what is in F5 cell? can you paste it here?

Comment: Sorry for the wait.
I've had to edit out the 'key' for security purposes, but here is all of the relevant info requested.
`http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key={REDACTED}&steamid=76561198021550319&format=xml`
https://puu.sh/DcYDE/c0d0e36f70.png

Comment: well, I can't really reproduce it so not really sure how to advise you. you can either try the other two solutions or wrapping import data fx in split like: `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({{transpose(split(IMPORTDATA(F5),char(10)); ""}, {""; transpose(split(IMPORTDATA(F5),char(10))}}, "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), ">(.*)<")`

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({{IMPORTDATA(F5); ""}, {""; IMPORTDATA(F5)}}, 
 "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), 
 ">(.*)<")`

Comment: Would you need the full link then?

Comment: Ah, by the way. The first formula gives a parse error, but the second formula does not. The second formula however, gives the Query completed with an empty output.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think we could achieve a similar result by having importdata throw it all into a single cell. Is that possible at all?

Comment: fixed that parse error: `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({{transpose(split(IMPORTDATA(F5),char(10))); ""}, {""; transpose(split(IMPORTDATA(F5),char(10)))}}, "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), ">(.*)<")`

Comment: "throw it all into a single cell" the 3rd answer does exactly that. did you try it?

Comment: The parse error is indeed fixed, yet that pesky Query complete with an empty output still persists, on both formulas. I know its not the source blocking the info from getting grabbed, because we can do it if we separate the data and the filter in the spreadsheet. By the way, here is your formula, with the full link included, no redacts.

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({{transpose(split(IMPORTDATA("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=38A89647F618D92C8AE3C9E292825D75&steamid=76561198021550319&format=xml"),char(10))); ""}, {""; transpose(split(IMPORTDATA("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=38A89647F618D92C8AE3C9E292825D75&steamid=76561198021550319&format=xml"),char(10)))}}, "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), ">(.*)<")`

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({{SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=38A89647F618D92C8AE3C9E292825D75&steamid=76561198021550319&format=xml"),CHAR(10)); ""}, {""; SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=38A89647F618D92C8AE3C9E292825D75&steamid=76561198021550319&format=xml"),CHAR(10))}}, "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Garry'", 0), ">(.*)<"))`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so very much, this really helps me learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("A"&FILTER(ROW(A:A), SEARCH("*Garry*", A:A))+1), ">(.*)<")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(A:A, , 999^99), 
 "Garry(.*)"), "2weeks>(\d+.\d+|\d+)")
```

[image: 0]